# When running into very long loops, get Segmentation Fault:11 or memory allocation error

Tags: c++, memory

The code is following, and the troublesome part of the code is the `getTop()` function:
there is a while loop in `calculate()` function, and the input file is very large, when I tried a small version with 2000 lines of input file to handle, the program never went wrong. But when I tried a large version with 130,000 lines of input file, I basically got two kinds of errors.

```
#include "UserUserSim.h"
UserUserSim::UserUserSim(string &query_url):
    _query_url(query_url)
{

}

void UserUserSim::calculate(ostream &out){
    ifstream infile(_query_url.c_str());
    string line;
    int movie_id;
    int user_id;
    MovieList* ml;
    while(infile>>line){
        if (line[line.length()-1]==':'){
            movie_id=atoi(line.c_str());
            ml=MovieDictionary::getInstance().getMovie(movie_id);
            ml->sortList();
            out<<line<<endl;
        }
        else{
            user_id=atoi(line.c_str());
            if (_map.find(user_id)==_map.end())
                getTop(user_id);
            float score=getScore(user_id,ml);
            out<<score<<endl;
        }
    }
}
float UserUserSim::getScore(int &user_id, MovieList* ml){
    vector<USim>* p=_map[user_id];
    vector<UserScore>::iterator it=ml->begin();
    vector<USim>::iterator sim_it=p->begin();
    float score=0;
    float score2=0;
    int total_num=0;
    float total_weight=0;
    int it_user_id;
    int sim_it_user_id;
    while( it != ml->end() && sim_it != p->end()){
        it_user_id=(*it).user_id;
        sim_it_user_id=(*sim_it).user_id;
        //cout<<it_user_id<<"  sdfsd "<<sim_it_user_id<<endl;
        if (it_user_id>sim_it_user_id)
            sim_it++;
        else if (it_user_id<sim_it_user_id)
            it++;
        else{ // when the user id matches
            score+=(*it).rating*(*sim_it).score;
            score2+=(*it).rating;
            total_num++;
            total_weight+=(*sim_it).score;
            sim_it++;
            it++;
        }
    }
    if (total_weight!=0)
        score=score/total_weight;
    else
        score=3.37827;//score2/total_num;
    return score;
}
typedef pair<int, float> mapPair;
bool compareSim(USim p1, USim p2){
    return p1.score>p2.score;
}
bool compareID(USim p1, USim p2){
    return p1.user_id<p2.user_id;
}
void UserUserSim::getTop(int user_id){
    vector<USim>* p=new vector<USim>;
    _map.insert(pair<int,vector<USim>*>(user_id,p));

    UserList* ul=UserDictionary::getInstance().getUser(user_id);
    vector<MovieScore>::iterator it;
    vector<UserScore>::iterator it_movie; // the iterator for the movielist
    vector<USim> score_list;
    vector<USim>::iterator it_s1;
    vector<USim>::iterator it_s2;
    for (it=ul->begin();it!=ul->end();++it){
        vector<USim> new_score_list;
        int movie_id=(*it).movie_id;
        it_s1=score_list.begin();
        MovieList* ml=MovieDictionary::getInstance().getMovie(movie_id);
        for(it_movie=ml->begin();it_movie!=ml->end();it_movie++){
            int user_id=(*it_movie).user_id;
            int rating=(*it_movie).rating;
            while( it_s1!=score_list.end() && user_id>(*it_s1).user_id){
                new_score_list.push_back((*it_s1));
                it_s1++;
            }
            USim us;
            us.user_id=user_id;     
            if (it_s1!=score_list.end() && user_id==(*it_s1).user_id){
                us.score=(*it_s1).score+rating*(*it).rating;// old allocated score+ new score
                it_s1++;
            }else{
                us.score=rating*(*it).rating;
            }
            new_score_list.push_back(us);// the vector's user rating x the rating of the movie,user
        }
        //copy the new_score_list into the score_list:
        score_list.clear();
        for (it_s2=new_score_list.begin();it_s2!=new_score_list.end();++it_s2)
            score_list.push_back(*it_s2);
    }
    int k=10;
    partial_sort(score_list.begin(),score_list.begin()+k,score_list.end(),compareSim);
    vector<USim>::iterator v_it;
    //store these users into the user_sim vector
    for (v_it=score_list.begin();v_it<score_list.begin()+k;++v_it){
        USim us=(*v_it);
        p->push_back(us);
    }
    sort(p->begin(),p->end(),compareID);
}
```

This is ERROR I:

```
recommend(71304) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f96d3ec8618: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
    Abort trap: 6
```

or the ERROR II:

```
Segmentation Fault:11
```

I checked the breakpoints when every time the error happens, they are all different, around the 50,000th line to the 100,000th line. So I guess this is a memory problem. And I also typed in ulimit before running the code, the error still happens. Really hope someone tell me where the bug lies in, or at least teach me how to debug the memory problem.

Comment: This code is not complete, and I'll bet it's not minimal.

Comment: At least try to narrow things down; perhaps with some trace statements via [std::cerr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr).

Comment: You could try to increase your stack size and see if that helps. In Visual Studio, see this link for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, there are more codes about the MovieDictionary, MovieList class etc. But they are supposed to be all read into memory for one time and never be modified after that. This part of code is just trying to access the in-memory data and do some calculation. Basically it is to multiply a matrix (5,000x10,000) and its transfer with a vector, but I optimized it by only calculating part of the matrix to save time.

Comment: Error 1 probably means you're writing to a dangling pointer (a pointer to memory that was once valid but was freed).  Error 2 means you trampled sufficiently far out of bounds as to wreck something pretty badly.  Are you on a system with `valgrind`?  If so, use it.  (If not, upgrade to a system that supports `valgrind`.)  Run in the debugger, like Error 1 says.  Set the breakpoint like it says, then run the program.  See where the trouble is.  Work back from there.

Comment: I just installed the valgrind, but I guess it is not working very well in OS X 10.8.... It makes my program seems to be about 20 times slower, impossible for me to wait for 50,000 lines until the error happens, it may take hours.......

Answer (score 2):

In method `UserUserSim::calculate` you have

```
MovieList* ml;
```

and you never initialize it, maybe when you invoke the `UserUserSim::getScore` method you are passing a null pointer which could be causing a segmentation fault.

Comment: I don't think it is the case, because the MovieList is initialized else where, and stored in memory for access. (A singleton map of <int, and pointer> plus a bunch of MovieList instances) Here I only need to get the pointer of it to use it for calculation.

Comment: are you sure? from the code you posted it seems like you are declaring ``ml`` instead of calling it from somewhere else

Comment: yes, see ml=MovieDictionary::getInstance().getMovie(movie_id). The MovieDictionary is a singelton, and the getMovie() function returns the instance of MovieList for given id.

Comment: I see that, but what if the last character from the first string you get from infile isn't a ':' ? it would go directly to the else statement and therefore calling a null pointer.

Comment: ermm... The input file is a quite standard one in the format like: movie_id: (1 line) user_id1(1 line) userid_2(1 line) userid_3.... And I tested it with a smaller input file with the same format of data, it works correctly...